# Use JIRA for Test Cases, without Zephyr

Tags: test-management, tools, jira

We are using Jira for product backlog and bug tracking, but not willing to pay for Zephyr, it's not really a big need for it. Is there any way to manage the test cases using simply JIRA?

1. I'm looking for a way to create test suites so i can easily handle them: i've tried linking them to the user stories or group them in sprints, but doesn't help much with the visibility, and it makes a mess with too many links on the user story.
2. I'm trying to "invent" a way to manage test results, to clearly see which tests have been run how many time, which ones are failed/passed etc. I've tried to use subtasks for each time i need to runt a test, but somehow it complicates more the whole thing and doesn't add visibility.

Anyone has any other working solutions?

Comment: Do we have an issue type as 'test case' in jira?

Comment: yes, there is a "test case" type of issue in JIRA. but i can't really do much with it, can make it passed or failled, can't really build reports on it, can't include it in specific test suits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have spent a couple of days to try and test [the Atlassian way of running tests in Jira from their confluence pages](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/Customise+JIRA+For+Test+Case+Management). After evaluation of others tools we decided to use [a commercial tool](http://www.gurock.com/testrail/) that integrated with Jira.

Example setup

- Create new Testcase issue type (with custom fields and status Passed/Failed)
- Create subtask of the issue (add version)
- Execute Testcase in subtask
- Filter on version and setup a report to see status

Pro's

- No plugins
- No extra costs

Con's

- Needs manual creation sub-tasks when running the test case
- No bulk test run setup

Comment: yeah, that's the setup i'm currently using too, but i find it a bit too much complicated/manual work and very little visibility (all tasks and subtasks and bug altogether, no way to view them grouped by features except having filters for each of them..). unfortunately i've worked with Microsoft Test Manager before which was pretty neat and i remained with too high standards, haha!

Comment: Agreed about TestRail, we use it too. Much better than TestLink anyway

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem does not have a good answer. The way Jira is built, having it alone manage testing is not worthwhile. Like you mentioned you need to see when the tests are run, what is the latest result, make test sets, link tests to defects and so on. While you could customize Jira to have more or less all of these, the solution would be too complicated to be well usable.

So if you do not want to use another software, I would try to keep it really simple. Like one big mutable test case per user story and it's status. Issues would link to this. It could have testing status like not tested after changes/failed/passed since changes. With simple solution you will not get so detailed report, but you can easily understand what it means what you see.

We had a different path. Like Niels we went for a commercial product. We took a [test management solution](https://www.melioratestlab.com/) that integrates with Jira. Our developers love Jira and our testers want to have issues on test management tool. Makes re-testing easy.

Answer (score 0):

JIRA by itself helps reflect test metrics in the form of built-in customizable dashboard widgets.You can use pie charts, graphs and heat maps to reflect the status of issues, their priority, the number of issues for each label and even the workload of the team members so that newer projects can be assigned optimally. You can learn more about JIRA dashboard by reading [this article](http://onpathtesting.com/jira-dashboard-reporting-metrics-for-better-qa-management/) on test effort management.